# how to return string from sqlite by using 2 string argument?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

here is my code for using that string

```
String item = item1.getText().toString();
        item = item.toLowerCase();
        String date = getDate();
        Datahelper edited = new Datahelper(this);
        edited.open();
            String returnedprice = edited.getprice(item,date);
        String returneddetail = edited.getdetail(item,date);
        edited.close();
            price.setText(returnedprice);
        details.setText(returneddetail);
```

and this is my method in sqlite

```
public String getprice(String item ,String date) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_DATE,KEY_PRICE,KEY_DETAILS};

         String whereClause = KEY_CATEGORY  + " = ? and " + KEY_DATE + " = ?";
         String[] whereArgs = {item,date};

         Cursor c = ourDatabase.query("DATABASE_TABLE", columns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);
            if(c!=null){
                String price = c.getString( c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE));
            return price;
            }

        return null;

    }

    public String getdetail(String item, String date) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_DATE,KEY_PRICE,KEY_DETAILS};

         String whereClause = KEY_CATEGORY  + " = ? and " + KEY_DATE + " = ?";
         String[] whereArgs = {item, date};

         Cursor c = ourDatabase.query("DATABASE_TABLE", columns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);
            if(c!=null){
                    String detail = c.getString( c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DETAILS));
                return detail;
                }

        return null;
    }
```

my app gets crash when using this code,, i dont know waht's wrong in the code if anyone need i can post the whole code pls help me

Comment: Can you add the logcat?

Comment: @fedepaol i am very new in android i dont know where it resides,, tell me how to get it..

Comment: It's the log you are getting from the adb view in eclipse

Comment: @fedepaol   where do i paste it?? its very big 85 lines

Comment: it doesn't matter it's big, just paste it as code the next time you're asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

the column index has nothing in common with the returned set:

```
String price = c.getString( c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE));
```

in `c` you have only 5 columns (0 to 4) ( `String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_DATE,KEY_PRICE,KEY_DETAILS};` ) and `c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE)` return the actual index in the table which is probably higher than 4.

instead of

```
String price = c.getString( c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE));
```

try

```
String price = c.getString(3);
```

Comment: that c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE) has nothing to do with that both statement r same having index value of 3.. @mihail but thanks for ur effort.. actually i have missed c.moveToFirst(); in if statement..

Answer (score 0):

the corect code is -

```
public String getprice(String item ,String date) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_DATE,KEY_PRICE,KEY_DETAILS};

     String whereClause = KEY_CATEGORY  + " = ? and " + KEY_DATE + " = ?";
     String[] whereArgs = {item,date};

     Cursor c = ourDatabase.query("DATABASE_TABLE", columns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);
        if(c!=null){
           c.moveToFirst();
            String price = c.getString( c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PRICE));
        return price;
        }

    return null;

}

public String getdetail(String item, String date) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_DATE,KEY_PRICE,KEY_DETAILS};

     String whereClause = KEY_CATEGORY  + " = ? and " + KEY_DATE + " = ?";
     String[] whereArgs = {item, date};

     Cursor c = ourDatabase.query("DATABASE_TABLE", columns, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, null);
        if(c!=null){
   c.moveToFirst();
    String detail = c.getString( c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DETAILS));
            return detail;
            }

    return null;
}
```